# Using Primitives Directly in Nashorn

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

I am developing a program which utilizes user scripts to customize a large portion of the experience. One of the consequences of the design is the fact that there are constant conversions from int/double/float into Number and back. The conversion causes a large amount of overhead and is therefor undesirable. For example:

Class referred to in Javascript:

```
class FromJava {
    public float getNum() {
        return 325.753;
    }

}
```

Javascript (executed in Nashorn with an instance of FromJava already put)

```
function doMath() {
  print(typeOf(obj.getNum()); // Prints "number"
}
```

Is there a way to prevent unnecessary boxing or is that a required overhead of the current Nashorn implementation?

Comment: What happens when getNum() returns an Integer?

Comment: Could you pass a Javascript object to getNum() and then fill it with a result? var myInt = 1; print(typeof(obj.getNum(myInt))). In java, modify myInt as appropriate.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, I will try it. It certainly will have some overhead, but should reduce it.